# Django For Loop with Javascript Math

Tags: javascript, html, django, math

I am trying to figure out how to run all my for loop values through this javascript math. For example, the individual value is a loop for all my inputs whereas the total value is fixed. Exp: Indivdual values are [10, 5, 20] and the total value is 100, I want the javascript to return 10/100, 5/100, and 20/100 to get pct's for each input. This is intended to fill out a table, so it should fill in each % in a table, for instance, the row "cookies" has 10% of total, the row "fish" has 5%, and the row "soup" has 20% of the total 100. Thanks.

```
let securities_in_asset = document.getElementById("asset-size").innerText;
securities_in_asset = parseInt(securities_in_asset)

for(let i = 0; i < securities_in_asset; i++) {

  let PctOfPool = document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="pct-of-pool"]`)[i]
  let indiviudal_value = document.getElementById("individual-market value").innerText;
  let total_value = document.getElementById("total-market-value").innerText;
  let problemTypeChoice = 0;

  if (problemTypeChoice === 0) {
    PctOfPool.innerText = `${((parseInt(indiviudal_value) / parseInt(total_value)) * 100).toFixed(2)}%`
  }

  else {
    PctOfPool.innerText = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: what is it currently returning as written?

Comment: Hi @saylestyler, it is generally only taking the first value in the loop and iterating that through all the table.      So the table looks something like (total value = 100),                                             Fish | 10 | .10     Cookies | 5 | .10       Soup | 20 | .10